# Ubuntu - Nginx client cert authentication: is a public CA a security risk?

Tags: nginx, ubuntu, ssl-certificate, reverse-proxy, client-certificate

I am struggling with a Nginx setup as reverse proxy with client certificate authentication. The client is only accepting publicly signed certificates to be imported as client certificates for authentication.

On the Nginx side I can setup the public available CA which was used to sign the client certificate (e.g. Let's encrypt) certificate with following settings (as suggested by many solutions):

```
ssl_client_certificate  /etc/nginx/ssl/ca.cer;
ssl_verify_client on;
```

I am now questioning the security of this setup and wanted to know if:

1. Any client using a valid client certificate signed by the public CA can now connect to the Nginx server and authenticate?
2. If the above answer is yes, how can I only allow my client certificate to be successfully authenticated and forbid the others?
   Do I need to specify my own CA (which will render this setup useless since the client side only allows public CA signed client certificates to be imported).

Thank you for your help.

Comment: No this is not a secure design. It also isn't the way most organizations handle certificate authentication. It's straightforward and expected that an organization would either have their own PKI and/or exercise the granularity to designate the root authorities that they trust, and remove authorities that they do not trust. The "publicly trusted" part of the requirements is unusual and probably naive. Also no organizations have only one factor of authentication, and it is a certificate not issued by them and not trusted by them for the purposes.

Comment: Letsencrypt doesn't even offer certificates for client authentication.

Answer (score 0):

For client certificates you should use a private ca, but Amazon AWS also offers private CA's.
https://aws.amazon.com/private-ca/

For nginx to use client certificates authentication you need to use these directives

```
    server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name your_domain.com;
    
        ssl_certificate /path/to/server.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /path/to/server.key;
        ssl_client_certificate /path/to/ca.crt;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
       ssl_ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305;  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers off;
    ssl_verify_client on;
    }
```

And you need to create a private ca and issue client certificates. In your Nginx configuration file, specify the paths to the server certificate, private key, and CA certificate (public part of your private CA). I also added some options to secure it